# Change column specification for single specific cells

Tags: tables, multicolumn, columns

Say I have a table with some data, a header row and a summary. The table has specific column specifications, like below

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\parskip{1em}
\begin{document}
    % Consider this table:
    \begin{tabular}{l@{~--~}l}%<- Makes a dash between columns
        NODASH1    & NODASH2   \\\hline
        beforedash & afterdash \\
        beforedash & afterdash \\\hline
        Sum        & NODASH!
    \end{tabular}

    Below, a possible workaround that I don't really fancy

    \def\nodash#1{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
    % Now using the \nodash to remove the dashes that I don't want
    \begin{tabular}{l@{~--~}l}
        \nodash{NODASH1} & NODASH2   \\\hline
        beforedash       & afterdash \\
        beforedash       & afterdash \\\hline
        \nodash{Sum}     & NODASH!
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:
[image]

So I'm looking for a more canonical way to produce the bottom table.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your write-up and code are slightly confusing. E.g., what is the purpose of the third column in both `tabular` environments?

Comment: @Mico yup - that was very confusing, and there wasn't supposed to be a third column! Is it clear now?

Comment: Another issue with your posting is that the title contains the qualifier "for only one single row". However, a careful reading of your posting suggests that you actually wish to change the column specification for *two cells*, not for *one row*. You may want to edit your posting to eliminate the need for people to guess as to what you really want to achieve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\multicolumn{1}` is the intended interface to specifying a different layout for heading or other rows. Note that you can get away with the simple

```
\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}
```

here as it is a left-aligned column.

For a right (or center) aligned column you would need

```
\multicolumn{1}{r@{\phantom{~--~}}{#1}}
```

so that the alignment didn't spread into the inter-column space generated by the `@`  expression in the main tabular preamble.